# Very Basic Question in using MySQL and XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, content-management-system, xampp

I am beginner in MySQL and I faced some terrific problems. please help me .

1 - I installed XAMPP in windows. Because of XAMPP has a MySQL I want to use MySQL but I can't how can I use MySQL ?(please explain me very basic because , I am real  beginner in database ) .

2 - If I install MySQL in my computer , Is it possible that MySQL in xampp and new MySQL that i am installed have conflict ?

3 - If I install .msi version of MySQL in my compyter, how can I run it to write code on it , create some table ,,,, ?

Special thanks.

Comment: Removed the [tag:sql-server] tag. MySQL <> SQL Server!

Answer (score 0):

1 - I would recommend that you attempt to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin - 
This is a great tool which helps you manage your databases.

2 - Yes, that is very possible. I recommend that you open task manager(ctrl+shift+esc) and check for duplicate mysql processes running.

3 - Once again - phpmyadmin is the easiest way to go.

Comment: My learning MySQL book writes its sql code in black environment link command prompt not in http://localhost/phpmyadmin/.

Comment: Well, if you are following a book, I understand why you may prefer to use the same interface as them. Navigate to your xampp installation folder(usually C:\xampp\xampplite), and go inside the mysql folder. Then enter the folder named "bin", and double click mysql.exe.